# Isotopy Classes and Embeddability of Products in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: gn.general-topology, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory, continuum-theory

On MSE I asked if the plane contains an uncountable collection of mutually disjoint copies of the Warsaw Circle; it seems to be false, and is probably already known but I'm not sure that anybody has ever published an explicit proof:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4006008/does-mathbbr2-contain-uncountably-many-disjoint-copies-of-the-warsaw-circl

I believe it's also false for the closed topologist's sine curve $T$.  I gave a sketch of a proof in the comments, but the different isotopy classes are making the bookkeeping task described in that method quite nasty.  For example, a ray spiraling around a closed arc is homeomorphic to $T$ (just picture it in $\mathbb{R}^3$ spiraling downward, and shift it).  Motivated by various attempts to find a more elegant proof, I was wondering the following.

Let $C$ be the Cantor Set and let $N = \lbrace 0 \rbrace \cup \lbrace \frac{1}{n}$ $|$ $n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ with the topology induced from $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that $X$ is a continuum and $f$ is an embedding of $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Suppose there is an embedding $\tilde{f}: X \times C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that its restriction to any $X \times \lbrace c \rbrace$ is isotopic to $f(X)$, where $c \in C$ (alternatively, suppose the same for $N$ instead of $C$).

Question: If $g$ is another embedding of $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\dim_H(f(X)) = \dim_H(g(X)) = 1$, is there a 'lifted embedding' $\tilde{g}: X \times C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ (respectively, a $\tilde{g}: X \times N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$)?  Here $\dim_H$ is the Hausdorff dimension.  If not, are there any sufficient requirements on the embeddings we consider to ensure that such is possible?

The reason that this might be useful is that if there is an uncountable collection of disjoint copies of a continuum $X$ in the plane, [then there is a copy](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419390142Z) of $X \times C$.  As well, for continua in the plane the isotopy extension problem [always has a solution](https://people.cas.uab.edu/%7Eoverstee/isotopy-07) so things tend to work out nicely.  In particular, 'strengthening' to ambient isotopy won't do anything.

However, there are copies of $N \times T$ in the plane such that the 'limit copy' has a different isotopy class than the rest (take the spiral embedding as the limit copy, then have your others marching toward it one tranche at a time as their free arcs converge to the spiral).  So for the case $X \times N$ it would be nice to ask the more elaborate version:

Suppose $\tilde{f}: X \times N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is any embedding with $\dim_H(\tilde{f}(X \times N)) = 1$.  If $g$ is an embedding of $X$ with $\dim_H(g(X)) = 1$ is there an embedding $\tilde{g} : X \times N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that its restriction to each coordinate is isotopic to $g$?  Stronger, if $g_n$ are such embeddings, can we get $\tilde{g}$ to be $g_n$ on each slice?  That one seems like too much, but maybe if we make a requirement about $g_0$ and how it relates to the others?

Thanks, hope it's interesting!

Comment: I should mention that I don't know much about the Hausdorff Dimension, this is just a way to try to avoid curves with positive area, which obviously mess things up.